# deduplicate: different file contents found in the following

Tags: sbt

I'm trying to build a project in SBT after I added a dependency on "org.apache" to the submodule.zookeeper" % "zookeeper" % "3.7.0" and catching a flurry of errors:

> ```
> [error] (assembly) deduplicate: different file contents found in the following:
> [error] C:\Users\****\AppData\Local\Coursier\cache\v1\https\repo1.maven.org\maven2\org\slf4j\log4j-over-slf4j\1.7.25\log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.25.jar:org/apache/log4j/Appender.class
> [error] C:\Users\****\AppData\Local\Coursier\cache\v1\https\repo1.maven.org\maven2\log4j\log4j\1.2.17\log4j-1.2.17.jar:org/apache/log4j/Appender.class
> [error] deduplicate: different file contents found in the following:
> [error] C:\Users\****\AppData\Local\Coursier\cache\v1\https\repo1.maven.org\maven2\org\slf4j\log4j-over-slf4j\1.7.25\log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.25.jar:org/apache/log4j/AppenderSkeleton.class
> [error] C:\Users\****\AppData\Local\Coursier\cache\v1\https\repo1.maven.org\maven2\log4j\log4j\1.2.17\log4j-1.2.17.jar:org/apache/log4j/AppenderSkeleton.class
> [error] deduplicate: different file contents found in the following:
> [error] C:\Users\****\AppData\Local\Coursier\cache\v1\https\repo1.maven.org\maven2\org\slf4j\log4j-over-slf4j\1.7.25\log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.25.jar:org/apache/log4j/BasicConfigurator.class
> [error] C:\Users\****\AppData\Local\Coursier\cache\v1\https\repo1.maven.org\maven2\log4j\log4j\1.2.17\log4j-1.2.17.jar:org/apache/log4j/BasicConfigurator.class
> [error] deduplicate: different file contents found in the following:
> [error] C:\Users\****\AppData\Local\Coursier\cache\v1\https\repo1.maven.org\maven2\org\slf4j\log4j-over-slf4j\1.7.25\log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.25.jar:org/apache/log4j/Category.class
> [error] C:\Users\****\AppData\Local\Coursier\cache\v1\https\repo1.maven.org\maven2\log4j\log4j\1.2.17\log4j-1.2.17.jar:org/apache/log4j/Category.class
> ```

How can this be fixed?

I tried to do this

```
"org.apache.zookeeper" % "zookeeper" % "3.7.0" exclude("org.slf4j", "slf4j-log4j12") exclude("log4j", "log4j")
```

, but it didn't help...